# SQLite: insert binary data from command line

Tags: sqlite, blob, binaryfiles

I have this SQLite table:

```
create table mytable (
aid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
bid INTEGER NOT NULL, 
image BLOB
);
```

And I want to insert a binary file into the `image` field in this table. Is it possible to do it from the `sqlite3` command line interface? If so, how? I'm using Ubuntu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a syntax like :

```
echo "insert into mytable values(1,1, \"`cat image`\")" | sqlite3 yourDb
```

i'm not sure for the " around blob's value. Note the backquotes around cat command, means the cat command will be executed before the echo.

[EDIT]

Blob are stored as hexa digit with "X" prefix. You can use "hexdump" unix command to produce the hexa string, but it would be better to write a command line tool that read image and do the insert.
More details on this post : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/64149

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this is only working for non-binary files. I am able to insert text but not jpg images for example, nor other type of binary data. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you need to encode binary file prior to insert them, with something like uuencode? the "cat" command maybe produce unusable output for a db insert

Answer (score 26):

The sqlite3 [command line interface](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) adds the following two “application-defined” functions:

- `readfile`
  which typically is used as: `INSERT INTO table(blob) VALUES (readfile('myimage.jpg'))`
- `writefile`
  which writes a file with the contents of a database blob and returns the count of bytes written.

Comment: This works on versions greater or equal to `SQLite Release 3.8.6 On 2014-08-15`