# How to write binary code of image png in a blob field using Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, blob, png, field

I'm using Sqlite and I should be able to write the binary code of the image in the blob field of my table.

the table is:  CREATE TABLE "Test00" ("Pk" Integer, "Image" Blob)

The path containing the image is C:\Users\acnxaa001525\Desktop\skillAssesment\napoli.png

Anybody can indicate me the query to write in the blob field the binary code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: IMHO It's not a good idea to store images in databases - you can't readily see or edit them there and they are generally large and make your database slower to back up. Filesystems are a good place for image files. Maybe you can just store a filename or unique identifier or reference in your database and keep the image itself in the filesystem. I'm always happy to be corrected if anyone thinks differently.

Comment: I really need to store the binary code of the imagine, can you indicate me the query to do it in Sqlite?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35960885/2836621

Comment: If your language's sqlite bindings support it, the [incremental blob api](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_blob_open) is a good way to efficiently store the image.